# how to insert an image in jupyter markdown in windows?

Tags: python, image, insert, markdown, jupyter

My OS is windows 10, I tried to insert an image in Jupiter markdown by the blow code but it didn't show anything:

`![image](ComplexNoProcV3.png)`

the image file is in the current working folder. However, same as below when I insert it in a code cell (not markdown) it shows properly:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
display(Image(filename='ComplexNoProcV3.jpg'))
```

Below you can see the outcomes of the codes the markdown cell does not show anything!! What is the issue? how could have the picture in the markdown version?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Make the cell as Markdown and write below code(my tea.jpg image is in same directory where my notebook is):

```
<img src='tea.jpg' width="400" height="400">
```

[image]

Comment: It did not work in windows 10.  Does    ![image](tea.png)    work on your system?

Comment: @HamidrezaAhadyDolatsara Yes, check your image extension(.jpg or .png)

Comment: I even downloaded your image but it still did not work. I can put URL of your picture and it is working. I guess the problem is from local system and the operating system. what is your operating system?

Comment: @HamidrezaAhadyDolatsara Windows 10, I know this would be difficult but can you re-install your anaconda?

Comment: I removed any instance of python and anaconda and re-install again! It's weird but I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all who responded to the question. I finally insert an image through the menu, and I found that it should be as below (it could be due to new version of anaconda):

```
![tea.jpg](attachment:tea.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my side.
if you want to display the only image on markdown cell,  is correct code.
The text in bracket may be any string.
I guess you didn't "run the markdown cell".
please try to change the cell type from code to markdown, then run it.
[image]

Comment: I ran it. It is the reason you see the word  'image' in the bottom of the posted picture, I guess there's some issues in windows OS 10. I checked some tutorials, all of them did in either Linux or mac os.

Comment: I used Markdown as you illustrated from the beginning but it doesn't work.